# Karma "illegal access" error when running ng test command

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, karma-runner

I am working on an angular 2 application that uses Karma to run the unit tests. As of a couple days ago when I run the `ng test` command after about a hundred tests I receive the following error:

```
11 06 2018 11:35:50.329:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.375:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.377:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.377:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.378:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.378:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.378:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
11 06 2018 11:35:50.379:ERROR [karma]: illegal access
```

And eventually Karma crashes with the following message:

```
(node:70069) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

However when I run  `ng test -sm=false` the tests all pass which leads me toward believing it's a problem with source maps.

At this point I am unsure what is causing these illegal access errors when running on my local machine. It seems to only be affecting my computer as I have had 2 other coworkers run the ng test command without issue.

Some things I have tried so far with no luck:

1. deleting my local git repository and redownloading
2. deleting and reinstalling webstorm
3. restarting my computer
4. running `sudo ng test`
5. increasing my version of npm to 5.8.0
6. increasing my version of node to 6.10.3
7. updating Java
8. invalidating WebStorm cash

Additonal information:

- OS: MacOS High Sierra v 10.12.6
- WebStorm: version 2018.1.4
- Karma: version 2.0.0
- Node: 6.10.3
- npm: 5.8.0
- angular-cli: 1.7.3